# Chrome tr height skips pixels

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having strange behaviour in Chrome when using 'height' property or my 'tr' elements.
If I set it to 25px rows will actually be 26px, one pixel larger and it behaves same for all sizes 25-29 or 35-39. If it is set to 20-24 or 30-34px it will display normally.

```
table tr { height: 25px; }
```

You can see it here in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uw53u/1/ .

Works good in FF.

NOTE:
I'm using Windows 7 and Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: Working fine on my chrome... all tr have 84px width and 25px height

Comment: @ViníciusMoraes What OS are u using? What Chrome version? I'll edit my post with this details.

Comment: Same as you win7 and Versão 26.0.1410.64 m are you using any chrome extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Windows7 and Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m is working fine your example, try to deactivate all your chrome extensions.

Comment: It's not the extensions. But I see now that although Dev tools display wrong pixel value rendering seems to respond fine.